# RestSharp latest version breaks my API's post method (add Guid before and after the body)

Tags: nuget, version, restsharp

Since latest version of RestSharp, all my post API's are failing because something has been added to the bodies I send.

Looks like a Guid id is generated and is added before and after the body for each call; the issue is it's not accepted by all my API's providers.

FYI, I created 2 identical console apps, one with version "106.12.0", and one with latest version "107.3.0". please see below the result:

Thanks in advance to help me with this
BR
-Vince

**Examples**:

**Working with Version="106.12.0" :**
**before**:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="application/xml"
  <SMSBoxXMLRequest>
  <username>cnoxxxx</username>
  <!-- password hidden -->
  <command>WEBSEND</command>
  <parameters>
    <service>VALAIS</service>
    <text>Test de Message Sms 1</text>
    <test></test>
    <receiver>+4177222333444</receiver>
  </parameters>
</SMSBoxXMLRequest>
```

**after**:
**Not Working with Version="107.3.0" :**

```
**--497993c6-3ef7-47fb-b527-403c1eefedf8**
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="application/xml"
  <SMSBoxXMLRequest>
  <username>cnoxxxx</username>
  <!-- password hidden -->
  <command>WEBSEND</command>
  <parameters>
    <service>VALAIS</service>
    <text>Test de Message Sms 1</text>
    <test></test>
    <receiver>+4177222333444</receiver>
  </parameters>
</SMSBoxXMLRequest>
**--497993c6-3ef7-47fb-b527-403c1eefedf8--**


**--3277a8db-bd83-4f3c-af2e-d34efe76fe98**
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="application/xml"
  <SMSBoxXMLRequest>
  <username>cnoxxxx</username>
  <!-- password hidden -->
  <command>WEBSEND</command>
  <parameters>
    <service>VALAIS</service>
    <text>Test de Message Sms 2</text>
    <test></test>
    <receiver>+4177222333444</receiver>
  </parameters>
</SMSBoxXMLRequest>
**--3277a8db-bd83-4f3c-af2e-d34efe76fe98--**


**--5b81fa95-a0b9-4f5c-9242-742734b0241e**
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="application/xml"
  <SMSBoxXMLRequest>
  <username>cnoxxxx</username>
  <!-- password hidden -->
  <command>WEBSEND</command>
  <parameters>
    <service>VALAIS</service>
    <text>Test de Message Sms 3</text>
    <test></test>
    <receiver>+4177222333444</receiver>
  </parameters>
</SMSBoxXMLRequest>
**--5b81fa95-a0b9-4f5c-9242-742734b0241e-**-
```

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose the issue as you haven't provided the code.

Comment: sorry about the delay; I had to ask the provider to create a temporary account with temp pwd....

I created a solution with 2 console app to repro my issue:
please find here a link to my OneDrive shared folder containing the solution
[link]https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqPUReudKR8tgomzaoUuBAlxsEGy0wY?e=1RSgvN

Hope you would be able to understand my issue.
Thanks in advance
BR
_Vince

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to spend time debugging your code. I just asked to provide the code snippet in the question, so it would be clear how you form your request.

Comment: I will restart it more officially as an issue on Github